# Can't connect to remote postgreSQL using psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to connect to a remote postgreSQL database, using the following code:

```
import psycopg2


try:

    # this:
    conn = psycopg2.connect(database="A B C", user="user", password="pass", host="yyyy.xxxxx.com", port= 5432)
    # or this:
    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=A B C user=user password=pass host=yyyy.xxxxx.com port=5432")
    # or this:
    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='A B C' user='user' password='pass' host='yyyy.xxxxx.com' port=5432")

    print "connected"

except psycopg2.Error as e:
    print "I am unable to connect to the database"
    print e.pgcode
    print e.pgerror
```

So if I am sure I have the correct database name, which has spaces in it like "A B C" in my example, and the correct username/password/host/port, why can I not connect?   Also, why does no error get passed onto the exception handler?  I am using python 2.7.9.  Here is the output, which is the same for any of the psycopg2.connect statements:

```
I am unable to connect to the database
None
None
```

Comment: AFAIK spaces are not allowed in PostgresQL schema names. Which is also what I read from http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Comment: Not every `psycopg2` exception has `pgcode` or `pgerror` set. You should print `e` as well to see the actual exception message.

Comment: Thanks, big help from both of you.  My colleague insists that database name is as presented, which maybe incorrect since the error I can now see says it is not.

Comment: Checked the name using pgAdmin and it is definitely correct without the spaces even though I am being told by psycopg2 that it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should see more info in `e` exception and also use very useful `traceback` module:

```
import traceback

...

except psycopg2.Error as e:
    print "I am unable to connect to the database"
    print e
    print e.pgcode
    print e.pgerror
    print traceback.format_exc()
```